# plone buildout with kgs in offline mode

Tags: plone, offline, buildout

My buildout.cfg for a plone project uses a kgs (known good set):

```
[buildout]
extends = http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2/versions.cfg
```

Since it's a network dependency, buildout does not work when being offline.

```
$ bin/buildout -o
While:
  Initializing.
Error: Couldn't download 'http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2/versions.cfg' in offline mode.
```

What is the best practice to work in offline mode *and* having kgs references? I assume there is some way to cache external references. Of course I could use a caching proxy locally but there must IMHO be a more lightweight solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We always download the KGS URLs to local files and use that as an extends instead:

```
curl -o plone-versions.cfg http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2.4/versions.cfg
```

where our `versions.cfg` reads:

```
[buildout]
extends = 
    zopeapp-versions.cfg
    ztk-versions.cfg
    zope-versions.cfg
    plone-versions.cfg
```

We add a header to the file to name the original source, and *comment out* the URL extends in the files:

```
# Sourced from http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2.4/versions.cfg
[buildout]
# extends = http://download.zope.org/zopetoolkit/index/1.0.7/zopeapp-versions.cfg
#          http://download.zope.org/Zope2/index/2.13.19/versions.cfg
```

Comment: Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster: We haven't bothered with it; sure, you can automate this, it's just text and URLs. But creating a buildout or upgrading the Plone version is going to involve far more than just caching these files. :-)

Comment: One way to automate it is to let someone else do it for you. Use the Unified Installer, or just download the version .cfg files from https://github.com/plone/Installers-UnifiedInstaller/tree/master/base_skeleton.

Comment: I am using this python script to recursively download the plone versions: https://gist.github.com/mauritsvanrees/1097587. Then I rename them for clarity and comment our the extends lines, just like Martijn mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the extends cache (which can also be shared between different machines such as your development machine and the production machine).

**Setup**

Add a file at `~/.buildout/default.cfg` for enabling the cache for all buildouts on this machine:

```
[buildout]
extends-cache = /path/to/your/extends/cache
```

Or you can do the same configuration in a specific buildout.

This will create files with hashed filenames in the directory you configure. Since the name of the file is generated by the URL of the extends, it can easily be copied around. So if you never have an internet connection on the server, you can run the buildout on another server with `extends-cache` and copy the direct

Answer (score -1):

I just made an odd observation, with could be of interest:

Changing the extends-url from

```
extends = http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2/versions.cfg
```

to

```
extends = http://dist.plone.org/release/4-latest/versions.cfg
```

will let buildout run without any errors (why?)

Might be a faster solution for your case, but Martijn's answer is of course the way to go for a replicable, controlled development-enviroment.

Comment: `4-latest` is just a symlink. If it ran without errors this time, you got lucky, there isn't anything different about it other than it being a symlink. It's not a good idea to use it however, as you'll run the risk of being upgraded to the latest 4.x version without being ready for it (add-ons no longer working, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I know that and use it for testing purpose to always have the newest version. Still doesn't explain, why with one config the error occurs, with another not and what exactly is ment with 'you got lucky'?

Comment: There is *no* difference between the two URLs as far as buildout is concerned. If one gave you an error, the other worked, then you got lucky that the second one worked. If you continue to have errors with one, then something *else* is broken, with a proxy or locally on your machine.

Comment: I don't have errors, I was reproducing the OP's error and just wondered what would be the difference. 'Got lucky' is no explanation 'your machine must be broken', neither, I think, but nevermind.

Comment: Just to be explicit: I did not downvote your post, I simply am commenting on the problems I do see with it.

Comment: If you tried to run in offline mode (`buildout -o`) and you didn't see the error, then you *already* have the requested file in your extends cache.

Comment: Now, that makes sense, thanks for the missing link! I'd probably should have opened a new quest instead of posting this as an answer, I just didn't know, which better place to put this observation.